# .NET MVC FluentValidation Not Working on a List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

All,

This is my 1st project using FluentValidation - I did read [the docs here](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/documentation) but for some reason, my list of objects is not being validated unobtrusively. The other non-list properties are validating unobtrusively just fine and ModelState is being reported as invalid in the controller, on form POST.

I can also see that the rendered HTML for the list properties does not contain the standard validation attributes.

**Being rendered like so:**

```
<input type="text" value="" name="Guitars[0].Make" id="Guitars_0__Make" placeholder="Make">
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

**Global.asax**

```
 FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
```

**The View Model**

```
 [FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(CustomerViewModelValidator))]
    public class CustomerViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Phone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public List<Guitar> Guitars { get; set; } 
    }
```

**The View Model Validator**

public class CustomerViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator
{

```
public CustomerViewModelValidator()
{
    RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotNull();
    RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotNull();
    RuleFor(x => x.Phone).NotNull();
    RuleFor(x => x.EmailAddress).NotNull();
    RuleFor(x => x.Guitars).SetCollectionValidator(new GuitarValidator());


}
```

}

**The List Validator**

```
 public class GuitarValidator : AbstractValidator<Guitar>
    {
        public GuitarValidator()
        {
            // All your other validation rules for Guitar. eg.
            RuleFor(x => x.Make).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.Model).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.ProductionYear).NotEmpty();
        }
    }
```

**The View**

```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


     <!-- List Object #1 -->
     <div id="cosponsorsTemplate_1">
            <div class="formColumn1"><label>Guitar</label></div>
            <div class="formColumn2">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guitars[0].Make, new { Placeholder = "Make" })
                <div class="messageBottom">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guitars[0].Make)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="formColumn3">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guitars[0].Model, new { Placeholder = "Model" })
                <div class="messageBottom">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guitars[0].Model)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="formColumn4">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guitars[0].ProductionYear, new { Placeholder = "Production Year" })
                <div class="messageBottom">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guitars[0].ProductionYear)</div>
                <a class="icon delete">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>

   <!-- List Object #2 -->
        <div id="cosponsorsTemplate_2">
            <div class="formColumn1"><label>Guitar</label></div>
            <div class="formColumn2">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guitars[1].Make, new { Placeholder = "Make" })
                <div class="messageBottom">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guitars[1].Make)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="formColumn3">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guitars[1].Model, new { Placeholder = "Model" })
                <div class="messageBottom">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guitars[1].Model)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="formColumn4">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guitars[1].ProductionYear, new { Placeholder = "Production Year" })
                <div class="messageBottom">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guitars[1].ProductionYear)</div>
                <a class="icon delete">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- List Object #3 -->
        <div id="cosponsorsTemplate_3">
            <div class="formColumn1"><label>Guitar</label></div>
            <div class="formColumn2">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guitars[2].Make, new { Placeholder = "Make" })
                <div class="messageBottom">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guitars[2].Make)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="formColumn3">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guitars[2].Model, new { Placeholder = "Model" })
                <div class="messageBottom">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guitars[2].Model)</div>
            </div>
            <div class="formColumn4">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Guitars[2].ProductionYear, new { Placeholder = "Production Year" })
                <div class="messageBottom">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Guitars[2].ProductionYear)</div>
                <a class="icon delete">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Obvious question here is did you add the following to your App_Start code?

    FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();

And did you also ensure that the JavaScript validation file was included in your _Layout.cshtml file?

Comment: Have you seen these two issues: http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/452754 and http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/272978?

Comment: I did not see these but it appears as though collection validation is only available server side: Collection validators are not supported on the client. Mvc's support for client-side ruled is very limited, and only a small subset of FluentValidation's rules can run on the client.